# Triggers vs Service Broker vs dedicarted Windows Service for high throughput asynchronous record processing via stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, windows-services, service-broker, triggers

**Overview**

I'm working on a web based solution that receives many millions of records a day (1000 at a time) via a web service from multiple clients simultaneously.

Each record needs to be stored in a database and use a complex set of rules and look-ups to work out how to classify each record, this is currently done via a stored procedure for ultimate speed (a record can be classified in about 4 milliseconds).

After classification the records needs to be moved to another database, and archived, this is the least important step and can be mainly left out of the question

**Main Priorities**

Priority 1 : Store the records, this is currently done via a bulk insert, and works well

Priority 2 : Classify each record, this is best done asynchronously, I.e this doesn't need to be done immediately (for each record) however it needs to happen in a timely manner and very efficiently

Priority 3 : Archiving, this is totally dependent on the clients requirements, it may need to be done immediately after classification, or in batch, and only needs to be an after thought at this stage

**Proposed Solutions**

My thinking has evolved since i first began this project

My first thought was to use a dedicated Windows Service to sit in the background and process batches of records, I.e check if there are records to classify, start a batch of N number of records, and repeat if necessary. However this solution requires a Windows Service (i'e another technology), and there may be a better approach

I've also been dabbling with the idea of triggers to process each record on update, however since I've never dealt with triggers, i'm am not sure whether it will slow down the bulk updates (step 1) how reliable they are or once again if there is a better approach

Lastly I've learnt of Service Broker, which seems to tick a lot of boxes in regards to asynchronous processing, reliability, and archiving / moving (last step), though i'm not sure if this over complicating the issue, if there are any performance sacrifices, and the extra boiler plating and black boxing is worth the effort

---

Please note: I would usually try every approach for myself, however the development time debugging, metrics analysis and learning curves with the approaches doesn't make it feasible, additionally it's outweighed by the time it might take to get some well rounded opinions from the Stack Overflow community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Triggers are synchronous, and will slow bulk inserts.  Service Broker is a good technology for async processing in T-SQL.  There is a bit of a learning curve, though, and it is important to follow best practice patterns (e.g. don't "fire and forget").  Make sure you have the unhappy paths covered since processing occurs in the background.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, in regaurds to service broker, given the above information above, would i queue a message for every new record, or some how make a batch solution, forgive my ignorance

Comment: Enqueue (SEND) a message for each batch containing the identifier of the batch ready to process.  This will launch the SB activated stored procedure associated with the queue.  The activated proc can then dequeue (RECEIVE) the message to process the batch identified in the message.  Note that you can have multiple instances of the activated proc run concurrently, according to the MAX_READER_COUNT specification of the queue definition.  I suggest you reuse conversations rather than start a new dialog for each batch to minimize SD overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a high input rate I would advise for simple polling, ie. an external service that polls constantly. Because, due to high input rate, it has a high rate of success at each poll. While is true that it requires an extra NT Service, with sll the baggage (specially vis-a-vis failover and Db HA) and is difficult to make throttle properly (too slow and it lags behind, too aggressive poll and it causes unnecessary work...), in the end is the fact that **it causes no extra IO** that shoul settle the mater. 
Service Broker is first and foremost a distributed technology, deals with communication between hosts. On a local only case, when you really want queuing not messaging, SSB has a lot of overhead. And SSB has state in the db, the SEND verb is one insert and two updates (min!) and BEGIN DIALOG is at least 2 inserts. If you think a naive SEND per incomming input record then you get a lot of extra IO. 
I also recommend reading http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/

Comment: Thanks, great answer, and i will respect it, as you have 10000 times more points then i do :) , However i might leave this question open for a while, as i don't need to start on the solution just yet